# Resume an interrupted Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

Is it possible to resume an interrupted `Thread` in Android?

Comment: AFIK this is not possible, you need to restart the thread.

Comment: @rekire How can I restart it?

Comment: Call start a second time. But you should note that the old states won't be restored.

Comment: @rekire So what should I do if I want to restore old states?

Comment: That depends on your code.

Comment: It throws an exception - could that not be caught?

Comment: @MartinJames Interrupt method? No, it's not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't resume Thread by its API, `resume()` method is depracated ([reason](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)).

You can simulate resuming Thread by killing it and starting a new one:

```
/**
Since Thread can't be paused we have to simulate pausing. 
We will create and start a new thread instead. 
*/
public class ThreadManager
{
    private static GameThread gameThread = new GameThread();

    public static void setRunning(boolean isRunning)
    {
        if (isRunning)
        {
            gameThread = new GameThread();
            gameThread.setRunning(true);
            gameThread.start();
        }
        else
        {
            gameThread.setRunning(false);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isRunning()
    {
        return gameThread.isRunning();
    }

    public static void join() throws InterruptedException
    {
        gameThread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: And replacement procedure?

Comment: So you have to store them outside the Thread and later pass it to the Thread. Let's say you store all your info in State class. You pass object of class State to the constructor of Thread and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

[Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) does not support these actions as related methods are deprecated.

- [suspend()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend%28%29)
- [resume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#resume%28%29)